# Torrent client for Emacs

Tags: emacs, software-rec, bittorrent

Does anybody know a bittorrent client for Emacs?

Comment: @AndrejaKo: THE Editor:) Sorry for the ambiguity, never thought it could be anything else when spelled just so!

Comment: @pooh It was just incredible to me that someone could expect EMACS to have a bittorrent client. +1 for asking that! One day, it will turn into whole operating system :)

Comment: @FndrejaKo: It was said to be one (the OS) since years! But that you know;)

Comment: @Andreja If Google thinks a browser could be an operating system Emacs  can all the more.

Comment: I know a good console client for Linux. Maybe you could try getting Linux to run in a VM inside emacs?

Answer (score 9):

Based on *sindikat's* answer, and surprisingly overlooked(?) by *Tony Stewart*, who shows `rtorrent` running in a `konsole` terminal... it seems that the way to get a working bittorrent client into *emacs* is to run `rtorrent` in a bash shell in *emacs*.. eg. `ansi-term`

`ansi-term` is a highly functional terminal emulator which is quite accessible via `elisp` commands ... To run `ansi-term` just type `M-x ansi-term`

Answer (score 2):

My answer for you is [rTorrent](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Filesharing/rTorrent-2673.shtml).

Menu:

[image]

Comment: .... Someone actually built a torrent client for EMACS? /facepalm

Comment: no, its a cli torrent client ;)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is none. http://emacswiki.org/ is a site, which documents everything concerning Emacs, including bazilions of its extensions. There is no mention of torrent-clients on the wiki and anywhere on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

## Mentor

> mentor is a GNU Emacs frontend for the rTorrent bittorrent client.

https://github.com/skangas/mentor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`2023 Update:` There is also this [transmission emacs interface](https://github.com/holomorph/transmission)

Emacs can do everything now!